# Is it possible to collapse variable List of Objects to specific depth in IntelliJ IDEA 2016 debugger with one click?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to collapse variable list of objects in `IntelliJ IDEA 2016` debugger to **specific depth** or **fully** with one click or shortcut?

Here is an example of what I need to do with one button/click:

**BEFORE collapsion:**
[image]

**AFTER collapsion:**
[image]

It would be much more comfortable, to be able to do such list collapsion, without clicking on each item in list individually, but just with one click on list (or other data structure with nested objects).

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, more like "How do I use this software?" I think it would be better to ask on the JetBrains support forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Comment: yeah, you are probably right, I will try to use forum and then answer my own Q if I find any useful answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not aware of a shortcut to expand all the nodes at once.

In order to avoid going on a clicking spree, though, there's the slightly quicker way: use the *Fully Expand Tree Node* action, which has *numpad*(*) as shortcut (or, *cmd+shift+A* and just start typing the action name).